# Error accessing google cloud storage through python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I need to use python to access files on google cloud storage. I'm using the following code -

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('json/file/path')
bucket = client.get_bucket('demo')
```

I get the following error -

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/iot-demo?projection=noAcl: storageaccess@zeta-bonsai-215512.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to demo.
```

Google Storage JSON API is enabled, I have given the 'storageaccess' account the 'Storage Admin' role. I have also tried giving the 'Project Owner' role.

Comment: Is "demo" the real bucket name? If so are you sure you own it? Common names like that are usually owned by someone else from a long time ago.

Comment: I just replaced the real bucket name with "demo" for the purpose of asking the question. The bucket I'm using is owned by me, and I have Storage Admin access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. My problem was that I created a service account that didn't have sufficient permissions. I deleted the service account and created a new one with the correct permissions. However, I named it the same as the old service account and it seems that GCP was defaulting to the old service account permissions. My solution was to create a new service account with a new name and the right role (`Storage Admin`) to apply the correct permissions.